# load multiple Domains on a single website

Tags: codeigniter, dns, uri

I have multiple domains

```
mysite.com - Main website
```

other domains

```
test.com
book.com
aaa.com
```

...

I have a website based on Codeigniter
I want to load other domains on this address

```
test.com (mysite.com/seller/test)
book.com ( mysite.com/seller/book)
aaa.com (mysite.com/seller/aaa)
```

I have these pages on seller websites

```
test.com/about 
test.com/contact
test.com/shop
```

it's load this page

```
mysite.com/seller/test/about
```

actually, it's like this

```
test.com/about (mysite.com/seller/test/about)
```

I have this on my Routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['404_override'] = 'index/lost';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['seller/(:any)/product/detail/(:num)'] = 'seller_product/detail/$2';
$route['seller/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'seller/$2/$1/';
$route['seller/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'seller/$2/$1/$3';
$route['seller/(:any)'] = 'seller/index/$1';
```

I hope you understand what I'm going to do
thanks for your help

Comment: i don't think what you are asking is easily achievable. someone else feel free to prove me wrong, but I know for a fact codeigniter doesn't have any methods to do this out of the box.

Comment: I don't insist on CodeIgniter , if it can be done with .httaccess so better! or do a thing on the host ( i have DirectAdmin server )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope it will work for you. set all domain path to root directory of your website. and make these changes in your route.php file

```
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
    case 'test.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "seller/test";
        $route['(.*)'] = "seller/test/$1";
    break;
    case 'book.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "seller/book";
        $route['(.*)'] = "seller/book/$1";
    break;
    case 'aaa.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "seller/aaa";
        $route['(.*)'] = "seller/aaa/$1";
    break;
    default:
        $route['default_controller'] = "index";
    break;
}
```